# Do Paul and Jesus disagree on homosexuality?

Tags: paul-apostle, homosexuality

Romans 1:26-27:

> [26] For this reason God gave them over to dishonorable passions. For their women exchanged the natural sexual relations for unnatural ones, [27] and likewise the men also abandoned natural relations with women and were inflamed in their passions for one another. Men committed shameless acts with men and received in themselves the due penalty for their error.

Jesus said nothing about homosexuality (from what we know) yet Paul teaches strongly against it (continuing in other verses). How do Christians who believe homosexuality is wrong justify the potential discrepancy here?

Comment: I think you're making too many assumptions here. Such as: Christ only taught what we have recorded in the gospels; Christ only shared with Paul what we have recorded in the gospels. Those are pretty large assumptions.

Comment: I've worked with Sven to make some edits and hopefully correct the tone and doctrinal direction of this post.

Comment: @JustinY. Another assumption is that the Pauline verses cited here have anything to do with homosexuality. Many would dispute that. We'll start with the first three words: *for what reason?*

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect. Jesus affirmed the enitre law of Moses which condemned homosexuality, therefore to claim he "said nothing about homosexuality" is just plain wrong. cf. [Matthew 5:17-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5%3A17-18&version=NIV).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are correct in stating that there are no recorded teachings of Jesus on homosexuality.  However, to suggest that this means there is disagreement between Paul and Jesus is unreasonable, since it is comparing something to nothing. **It is certainly wrong to assume that Jesus disagreed with Paul on that just because He never explicitly indicates His agreement -- with Paul and the Law of Moses**.

Indeed, if Jesus had disagreed with Moses on this, we should expect to hear about it in His teaching. If, however, He agreed with Moses, then why go to great pains to point that out?

It should be noted that Jesus was Jewish and lived among Jewish people in a Jewish culture.  This whole culture was based on Mosaic teachings that held that homosexuality was wrong and had a very stiff penalty spelled out for it, much like adultery. People caught in adultery still suffered the possibility of death (see [John 8:1-11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%208:1-11&version=NASB)). It is quite likely that this was simply not practiced in this culture.

Jesus never taught that eating pork was wrong either, because everyone in that culture agreed with that and no one ate pork. The idea of "preaching to the choir" about getting involved in the church comes to mind.

During Jesus' life, Israel was still under the Old Covenant, so the prohibition against eating pork was still in effect. Paul's writings occur in the New Testament, but reaffirm the prohibition of Moses against homosexuality.

So, there's absolutely no "discrepancy", and any intimation that Jesus supported homosexuality is not reasonable.

Jesus "did not come to abolish the Law, but to fulfill it" [[Matthew 5:17]](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:17&version=NASB).

Comment: also note that Paul was writing to [dominantly] non-Jewish people in Romans - who would be unfamiliar with the laws given to Israel

Comment: Your answer here is inconsistent. Without good cause, you can't ascribe different verdicts on "pork", "mixed crops", "shellfish" and "homosexuality". Either those laws stand or they don't. If he didn't come to abolish the law, do you still follow Mosaic / Jewish law?

Comment: @MarcGravell Acts 15 states that the Mosaic Law does not apply to Gentiles (or even Jewish Christians), but one thing they still prohibited was "sexual immorality".

Answer (score 10):

If Jesus did not in fact say that, it doesn't mean that Paul and Christ are in contradiction with one another. Not saying something does not mean acceptance or approval.

That said, Jesus has made a stand and voiced opposition against homosexuality. *Just not while He was performing his ministry here on earth.*

First, **Jesus is God**: John 8:58 - Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.”

Second, Jesus existed before the earth began: John 1:3 - All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.

Third, **God said from the beginning that it stands against his law**: Gen 19:4-11, Lev 18:22.

Fourth, Jesus entered the world not to abolish the law but to fulfill it: Matthew 5:17.

Fifth, Paul and the other apostles being filled with the Holy Spirit of Truth would not preach a different gospel than their Messiah.

Comment: Its not very clear how your five points directly relate to this point: "That said, Jesus has made a stand and voiced opposition against homosexuality."

Comment: I see it.. If Jesus is God, and God took a stand against homosexuality, then it may not be mentioned in the Gospels or His ministry here on earth, but again, if Jesus is God, then He said it in the verses cited  @Brian, I edited to clarify the point I *think* you were making.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.

Comment: David, that is exactly what I meant so thank you. In connecting the dots with the other verses, I was also trying to end other arguments that might arise that would either say: Jesus did not exist in the Old Testament, or Jesus' law of salvation invalidated the law of condemnation.

Answer (score 9):

Jesus said to keep the commandments, including the commandment against Adultery (Matthew 19:16–19)

The commandments against adultery form the basis for the Catholic teaching against homosexual acts and all sexual acts outside of marriage.  These teachings all fall under an explanation of the sixth commadnment:

> **Chastity and homosexuality**
>
> Homosexuality refers to relations between men or between women who experience an exclusive or predominant sexual attraction toward persons of the same sex. It has taken a great variety of forms through the centuries and in different cultures. Its psychological genesis remains largely unexplained. Basing itself on Sacred Scripture, which presents homosexual acts as acts of grave depravity, tradition has always declared that "homosexual acts are intrinsically disordered." They are contrary to the natural law. They close the sexual act to the gift of life. They do not proceed from a genuine affective and sexual complementarity. Under no circumstances can they be approved.
>
> The number of men and women who have deep-seated homosexual tendencies is not negligible. This inclination, which is objectively disordered, constitutes for most of them a trial. They must be accepted with respect, compassion, and sensitivity. Every sign of unjust discrimination in their regard should be avoided. These persons are called to fulfill God's will in their lives and, if they are Christians, to unite to the sacrifice of the Lord's Cross the difficulties they may encounter from their condition.
>
> Homosexual persons are called to chastity. By the virtues of self-mastery that teach them inner freedom, at times by the support of disinterested friendship, by prayer and sacramental grace, they can and should gradually and resolutely approach Christian perfection.

[CCC 2357-2359](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p3s2c2a6.htm)

Adultery may mean many things to many people, but the Church is clearly free to expand on what she considers adultery to encompass and it's perfectly rational that any sex outside of marriage is adultery on account of

1. that person you're having relations with may one day be someone else's bride or husband and
2. you may one day be someone else's bride or husband.

By this definition, and since 'homosexual marriage' is a spiritual and physical impossibility, every homosexual act must be adultery, at least in a spiritual sense.

Comment: +1 because back then, the thought of homosexual marriage wasn't considered.  Although people had relationships with the same sex that today we would consider inappropriate, the thought of marriage (which is a union to create more children) with the same sex wasn't considered at all.

Comment: @Trig - I reverted your changes because you were incorrectly making a doctrinal point in removing the "physical" impossibility of marriage.  The physicality of "one flesh" is impossible in Catholic (and many other) understanding, and hence it is not "an obvious absurdity"

Comment: The problem in part here is that much of Christianity gets so much more excited about homosexuality than it does about plain old adultery...

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm inclined to agree with you, but for a different reason. 1) Your statement is true, and in this respect Christianity is wrong for the unbalance. 2) Much of it stems from the fact that a disproportionately greater number of people are claiming that homosexuality is not wrong than are claiming that plain old adultery is not wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There's a passage that gets overlooked almost uniformly when addressing this question.  In Matthew 15, while addressing the business of traditional handwashing, Jesus said:

> 19 For out of the heart come evil thoughts—murder, adultery, sexual
>   immorality, theft, false testimony, slander. 20 These are what defile
>   a person; but eating with unwashed hands does not defile them.”

"Sexual immorality" translates the Greek word *porneia*, which was a catch-all word to describe any kind of forbidden sexual contact:  adultery, homosexuality, intercourse with animals, etc.  (It's akin to the way "stealing" covers any kind of unlawful taking of property: robbery, burglary, fraud, embezzlement, etc.)

The point being, Jesus affirmed in this passage that **all forms of forbidden sexual contact were evil,** just like murder, theft, false testimony, and so on.  Both He and His audience would have known that this included homosexuality, and He stated no exception for it.

TLDR: Jesus did affirm that homosexual activity is a sin.

Comment: Was adultery not a "forbidden sexual contact" or immoral?

Comment: Yes, it was forbidden too -- Jesus included it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus talked about marriage, and reiterated that it is between a man and a woman. So if you go just on Jesus' words, you know homosexual marriage is a sin.

Comment: You're right, but it would be helpful to cite the reference.  (For this reason a man shall leave his mother and be joined...)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Hebrews 11;3  Through  faith  we  understand  that  the  worlds  were  framed  by  the  word  of  God,  so  that  things  which  are  seen  were  not  made  of  things  which  do appear.

John 1  In  the  beginning  was  the  Word,  and the  Word  was  with  God,  and  the  Word  was  God.
John 1;14  And  the  Word  was  made  flesh,  and  dwelt  among  us, (and  we  beheld  his  glory,  the  glory  of the  only  begotten  of  the  Father,)  full  of  grace  and  truth.
Colossians 1; 12,13,14,16  Giving  thanks  unto the Father,  which  hath  made  us  meet  to  partakers  of  the  inheritance  of  the  saints  in  light:  Who  hath delivered  us  from  the  power  of  darkness,  and  hath  translated  us into  the  kingdom  of  his  dear  Son:  In  whom  we  have  redemption  through  his  blood,  even  the  forgiveness  of  sins:  For  by  him  were  all  things  created,  that  are  in  heaven,  and  that  are  in  the  earth,  visible and  invisible,  whether  they  be  thrones,  or  dominions,  or  principalities,  or  powers:  all  things  were  created  by  him,  and  for  him:

John 1;17  For  the  law  was  given  by  Moses,  but  grace  and  truth  came  by  Jesus  Christ.
Psalms  119;142  Thy  righteousness  is  everlasting  righteousness,  and  thy  law  is  truth.

Genesis 19;4-5  But  before  they  lay  down,  the  men  of  the  city,  even  the  men  of  Sodom  compassed  the  house  round,  both  old  and  young,  all  the  people  from  every  quarter:  And  they  called  unto  Lot,  and  said  unto  him,  Where  are  the  men  which  came  in  to  thee  this  night?  bring  them  out  unto  us,  that  we  may  know  them.
Genesis 19;13  For  we  will  destroy  this  place,  because  the  cry  of  them  waxen  great  before  the  face  of  the  LORD:  and  the  LORD  hath  sent  us  to  destroy  it.

Homosexuality  was  rampant  well  before  Paul's  time.  God's  judgement  required  the  destruction  of  Sodom  and  Gomorrah.

Hebrews 4;12  For  the  word  of  God  is  quick,  and  powerful,  and  sharper  than  a  twoedged  sword,  piercing  even  to  the  dividing  assunder  of  soul  and  spirit,  and  of  the  joints  and  marrow,  and  is  a  discerner  of  thoughts  and  intents  of  the  heart. 
1 Peter 1;25  But  the  word  of  the  LORD  endureth  for ever.  And  this  is  the  word  which  by  the  gospel  is  preached  unto  you.